# postgresql trigger for updating multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, update

i have a column in a certain table that i want to match to a column in a different table in a PostgreSQL database, so i tried creating a trigger that could accomplish that:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modify_res_partner() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
UPDATE res_partner
SET x_street1=res_partner_address.street
FROM res_partner_address
WHERE res_partner.id=res_partner_address.partner_id;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER modify_res_partner_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON res_partner_address
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE modify_res_partner();
```

the 2 tables share the same value of `partner_id` for each record, but as you may have guessed, this trigger executes queries for every true condition, so when i modify one record on the first table, the trigger causes 800 (for example) modification to occur for every matching `partner_id` pair.

how can i modify the record alone that matches the modified record on the first table?

Comment: Your question belongs to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your query to become like this:

```sql
UPDATE res_partner
SET x_street1=res_partner_address.street
FROM res_partner_address
WHERE res_partner.id = NEW.partner_id;
```

You should make use of the `NEW` row. This refers to the inserted row in case of `INSERT` operation. It also refers to the updated row in case of `UPDATE` operation.

By the way, you don't need to create the trigger for `DELETE` operation.

Comment: thank you khaled, i worked with NEW before but when dealing with char types u need to add a bunch of quotes and pipes to work.